# laser_self_filter crashes when launching PR2 arm_navigation

Tags: pcl, arm-navigation, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is basically a problem reported [before](http://answers.ros.org/question/46821/problem-with-pr2-right_arm_navigation/) by @ASchwa but never got resolved.
Though it is a wiki question, I don't have enough Karma, so I am posting as new question.

I just want to run `roslaunch pr2_3dnav right_arm_navigation.launch`

laser_self_filter continues to crash and gets respawned on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64-bit with ROS Fuerte.

I know this launch file does work on many other machines that also runs 12.04 64bit with Fuerte.
It is crucial for us to get this working please take a look.

As @Lorenz suggested, I attached gdb to laser_self_filter. Please take a look. Thanks!

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00007ffff6ae20e1 in pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PointXYZ>::applyFilter(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>&) () from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_filters.so.1.5
#1  0x0000000000434527 in filter (output=..., this=0x7fffffffdb10)
    at /opt/ros/fuerte/include/pcl-1.5/pcl/filters/filter.h:117
#2  SelfFilter::cloudCallback (this=0x7fffffffd600, cloud2=...)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-arm-navigation-1.1.11/debian/ros-fuerte-arm-navigation/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/arm_navigation/robot_self_filter/src/self_filter.cpp:105
#3  0x0000000000424b3a in operator() (a0=..., this=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1013
#4  boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<boost::function<void (boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)>, void, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > const> >::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > const>) (function_obj_ptr=..., a0=...)
    at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:153
#5  0x000000000043821c in operator() (
    a0=<error reading variable: access outside bounds of object referenced via synthetic pointer>, this=0x698238) at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1013
#6  message_filters::CallbackHelper1T<boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >::call (this=0x698230, event=..., nonconst_force_copy=<optimized out>)
    at /opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/signal1.h:76
#7  0x000000000042a367 in call (event=..., this=<optimized out>)
    at /opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/signal1.h:119
#8  message_filters::SimpleFilter<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >::signalMessage (this=<optimized out>, event=...)
    at /opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/simple_filter.h:135
#9  0x000000000043b365 in tf::MessageFilter<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >::testMessage (this=0x7a2970, evt=...)
    at /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry/tf/include/tf/message_filter.h:413
#10 0x000000000043bf91 in tf::MessageFilter<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >::add (this=0x7a2970, evt=...)
    at /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry/tf/include/tf/message_filter.h:255
#11 0x0000000000438408 in operator() (a0=..., this=0x7c05f8)
    at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1013
#12 message_filters::CallbackHelper1T<ros::MessageEvent<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >::call (this=0x7c05f0, event=..., nonconst_force_copy=<optimized out>)
    at /opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/signal1.h:76
#13 0x000000000042a367 in call (event=..., this=<optimized out>)
    at /opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/signal1.h:119
#14 message_filters::SimpleFilter<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >::signalMessage (this=<optimized out>, event=...)
    at /opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/simple_filter.h:135
#15 0x000000000043853b in operator() (a0=..., this=0x7e4458)
    at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1013
#16 ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperT<ros::MessageEvent<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, void>::call (this=0x7e4450, params=...)
    at /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/subscription_callback_helper.h:180
#17 0x00007ffff77252b7 in ros::SubscriptionQueue::call() ()
   from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#18 0x00007ffff76d7ce9 in ros::CallbackQueue::callOneCB(ros::CallbackQueue::TLS*) ()
   from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#19 0x00007ffff76d978b in ros::CallbackQueue::callAvailable(ros::WallDuration) ()
   from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#20 0x00007ffff7728b08 in ros::SingleThreadedSpinner::spin(ros::CallbackQueue*) ()
   from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#21 0x00007ffff770db0b in ros::spin() () from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#22 0x000000000041db23 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdcf8)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-arm-navigation-1.1.11/debian/ros-fuerte-arm-navigation/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/arm_navigation/robot_self_filter/src/self_filter.cpp:145

(gdb) thread apply all bt

Thread 8 (Thread 0x7fffcffff700 (LWP 25559)):
#0  0x00007ffff55010fe in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff76bacff in ros::TimerManager<ros::Time, ros::Duration, ros::TimerEvent>::threadFunc() () from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#2  0x00007ffff4f29ce9 in thread_proxy () from /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1
#3  0x00007ffff54fce9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff5229cbd in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 7 (Thread 0x7fffe4919700 (LWP 25357)):
#0  0x00007ffff55010fe in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff76dbf1b in bool boost::condition_variable::timed_wait<boost::date_time::subsecond_duration<boost::posix_time::time_duration, 1000000l> >(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&, boost::date_time::subsecond_duration<boost::posix_time::time_duration, 1000000l> const&) () from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#2  0x00007ffff76d98c9 in ros::CallbackQueue::callAvailable(ros::WallDuration) ()
   from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#3  0x00007ffff7bbbb5a in tf::TransformListener::dedicatedListenerThread (
    this=0x69aea0)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-geometry-1.8.2/debian/ros-fuerte-geometry/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry/tf/include/tf/transform_listener.h:187
#4  0x00007ffff4f29ce9 in thread_proxy () from /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1
#5  0x00007ffff54fce9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#6  0x00007ffff5229cbd in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 6 (Thread 0x7fffe511a700 (LWP 25349)):
#0  0x00007ffff55010fe in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff76dbf1b in bool boost::condition_variable::timed_wait<boost::date_time::subsecond_duration<boost::posix_time::time_duration, 1000000l> >(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&, boost::date_time::subsecond_duration<boost::posix_time::time_duration, 1000000l> const&) () from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#2  0x00007ffff76d98c9 in ros::CallbackQueue::callAvailable(ros::WallDuration) ()
   from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#3  0x00007ffff7bbbb5a in tf::TransformListener::dedicatedListenerThread (
    this=0x7fffffffd600)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-geometry-1.8.2/debian/ros-fuerte-geometry/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry/tf/include/tf/transform_listener.h:187
#4  0x00007ffff4f29ce9 in thread_proxy () from /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1
#5  0x00007ffff54fce9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#6  0x00007ffff5229cbd in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 5 (Thread 0x7fffe591b700 (LWP 25346)):
#0  0x00007ffff55010fe in pthread_cond_timedwait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff76dbf1b in bool boost::condition_variable::timed_wait<boost::date_time::subsecond_duration<boost::posix_time::time_duration, 1000000l> >(boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex>&, boost::date_time::subsecond_duration<boost::posix_time::time_duration, 1000000l> const&) () from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#2  0x00007ffff76d98c9 in ros::CallbackQueue::callAvailable(ros::WallDuration) ()
   from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#3  0x00007ffff770d87e in ros::internalCallbackQueueThreadFunc() ()
   from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#4  0x00007ffff4f29ce9 in thread_proxy () from /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1
#5  0x00007ffff54fce9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#6  0x00007ffff5229cbd in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
Thread 4 (Thread 0x7fffe611c700 (LWP 25339)):
#0  0x00007ffff5500d84 in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 ()
   from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x00007ffff7708a32 in ros::ROSOutAppender::logThread() ()
   from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#2  0x00007ffff4f29ce9 in thread_proxy () from /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1
#3  0x00007ffff54fce9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#4  0x00007ffff5229cbd in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 3 (Thread 0x7fffe691d700 (LWP 25338)):
#0  0x00007ffff5223023 in select () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff6db8176 in XmlRpc::XmlRpcDispatch::work(double) ()
   from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libxmlrpcpp.so
#2  0x00007ffff76b2aa7 in ros::XMLRPCManager::serverThreadFunc() ()
   from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#3  0x00007ffff4f29ce9 in thread_proxy () from /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1
#4  0x00007ffff54fce9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#5  0x00007ffff5229cbd in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#6  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 2 (Thread 0x7fffe711e700 (LWP 25337)):
#0  0x00007ffff521e303 in poll () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff76bdc76 in ros::poll_sockets(pollfd*, unsigned long, int) ()
   from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#2  0x00007ffff772ed7a in ros::PollSet::update(int) ()
   from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#3  0x00007ffff76cc3b4 in ros::PollManager::threadFunc() ()
   from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#4  0x00007ffff4f29ce9 in thread_proxy () from /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1
#5  0x00007ffff54fce9a in start_thread () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#6  0x00007ffff5229cbd in clone () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#7  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()

Thread 1 (Thread 0x7ffff7fb0800 (LWP 25207)):
#0  0x00007ffff6ae20e1 in pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PointXYZ>::applyFilter(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>&) () from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libpcl_filters.so.1.5
#1  0x0000000000434527 in filter (output=..., this=0x7fffffffdb10)
    at /opt/ros/fuerte/include/pcl-1.5/pcl/filters/filter.h:117
#2  SelfFilter::cloudCallback (this=0x7fffffffd600, cloud2=...)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-arm-navigation-1.1.11/debian/ros-fuerte-arm-navigation/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/arm_navigation/robot_self_filter/src/self_filter.cpp:105
#3  0x0000000000424b3a in operator() (a0=..., this=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1013
#4  boost::detail::function::void_function_obj_invoker1<boost::function<void (boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&)>, void, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > const> >::invoke(boost::detail::function::function_buffer&, boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > const>) (function_obj_ptr=..., a0=...)
    at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:153
#5  0x000000000043821c in operator() (
    a0=<error reading variable: access outside bounds of object referenced via synthetic pointer>, this=0x698238) at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1013
#6  message_filters::CallbackHelper1T<boost::shared_ptr<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >::call (this=0x698230, event=..., nonconst_force_copy=<optimized out>)
    at /opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/signal1.h:76
#7  0x000000000042a367 in call (event=..., this=<optimized out>)
    at /opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/signal1.h:119
#8  message_filters::SimpleFilter<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >::signalMessage (this=<optimized out>, event=...)
    at /opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/simple_filter.h:135
#9  0x000000000043b365 in tf::MessageFilter<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<vo---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---
id> > >::testMessage (this=0x7a2970, evt=...)
    at /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry/tf/include/tf/message_filter.h:413
#10 0x000000000043bf91 in tf::MessageFilter<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >::add (this=0x7a2970, evt=...)
    at /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/geometry/tf/include/tf/message_filter.h:255
#11 0x0000000000438408 in operator() (a0=..., this=0x7c05f8)
    at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1013
#12 message_filters::CallbackHelper1T<ros::MessageEvent<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >::call (this=0x7c05f0, event=..., nonconst_force_copy=<optimized out>)
    at /opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/signal1.h:76
#13 0x000000000042a367 in call (event=..., this=<optimized out>)
    at /opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/signal1.h:119
#14 message_filters::SimpleFilter<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > >::signalMessage (this=<optimized out>, event=...)
    at /opt/ros/fuerte/include/message_filters/simple_filter.h:135
#15 0x000000000043853b in operator() (a0=..., this=0x7e4458)
    at /usr/include/boost/function/function_template.hpp:1013
#16 ros::SubscriptionCallbackHelperT<ros::MessageEvent<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2_<std::allocator<void> > const> const&, void>::call (this=0x7e4450, params=...)
    at /opt/ros/fuerte/include/ros/subscription_callback_helper.h:180
#17 0x00007ffff77252b7 in ros::SubscriptionQueue::call() ()
   from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#18 0x00007ffff76d7ce9 in ros::CallbackQueue::callOneCB(ros::CallbackQueue::TLS*) ()
   from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#19 0x00007ffff76d978b in ros::CallbackQueue::callAvailable(ros::WallDuration) ()
   from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#20 0x00007ffff7728b08 in ros::SingleThreadedSpinner::spin(ros::CallbackQueue*) ()
   from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#21 0x00007ffff770db0b in ros::spin() () from /opt/ros/fuerte/lib/libroscpp.so
#22 0x000000000041db23 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffdcf8)
    at /tmp/buildd/ros-fuerte-arm-navigation-1.1.11/debian/ros-fuerte-arm-navigation/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/arm_navigation/robot_self_filter/src/self_filter.cpp:145
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56179/laser_self_filter-crashes-when-launching-pr2-arm_navigation/) by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2013-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm getting the same error if I try to run a launchfile from the erratic_robot package (roslaunch erratic_navigation_apps demo_2dnav_empty_map.launch). I'm also running Ubuntu 12.04 64-Bit with Fuerte.

UPDATE:
Have a look at this ticket: https://github.com/ros-perception/perception_pcl/issues/10

---

Originally posted by [alex_rockt](https://answers.ros.org/users/5037/alex_rockt/) with karma: 76 on 2013-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0